# ¿Cómo seleciono el primer número de una cadena?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

El comando `cat /etc/redhat-release` devuelve:

```
 CentOS Linux release 5.6.1804 (Core)
```

¿Cómo selecciono solo el 5?

He probado

```
 cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print $4}'
```

y me devueve esto:

```
5.6.1804
```

pero yo solo quiero el primer numero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes con una combinación de `awk` y `cut`

```
$ awk '{print $4}' /etc/redhat-release | cut -f 1 -d .
```

O con `grep`

```
$ grep -oP "(?<= )[[:digit:]]+(?=.)" /etc/redhat-release
```

El cual obtiene los dígitos que esté entre un espacio y un punto.

Otra variante de `grep` es:

```
$ grep -oE "[[:digit:]]+" /etc/redhat-release | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres usar `awk` solo te restaría obtener el primero de los dígitos, lo cual puedes resolver fácilmente usando [`split()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
awk '{split($4, release, ".");print release[1]}' /etc/redhat-release
```

Está función construirá un arreglo separando el valor del release por cada punto. El primer valor de este arreglo será el numero de versión que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print $4}' /etc/redhat-release |awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
```

El primer **awk** permite seleccionar el cuarto campo de la línea, luego se agrega otro awk para procesar la salida del primero y tomar al punto (**.**) como separador. En esta forma se selecciona el primer campo de la primera salida y así dar solución al problema planteado

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: además, hacer dos llamadas a awk para dos acciones diferentes parece poco práctico

Comment: Emilio, debes agregar una descripción a tu respuesta *(ya que tu respuesta apareció en la lista de revisión de publicaciones de baja calidad)*.